# Testing airflow dags with KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: airflow, kubernetespodoperator

We have a sort of self-serve Airflow cluster that mandates that all of the tasks are wrapped as KubernetesPodOperator tasks. With this setup what are the possible options to test the dags in CI/CD setup?

Comment: What do you mean by wrapped? Can you give an example how do you expect to actually do that? Lets say that someone wrote `DockerOperator` with `environment` parameter. You can't just wrap this with `KubernetesPodOperator`. You will need to convert the`environment` dict into a list of `V1EnvVar` Wouldn't it be simpler to use Kubernetes Executor? With that the executor will create a new pod for every task instance

Comment: By wrapped I meant, any tasks will be encapsulated as a docker container and the dag will have several KubernetesPodOperator that will run these containers in our Airflow cluster (no other operators are allowed). The question of "is this the right way to run airflow" aside, how do we test these KubernetesPodOperator tasks ?

Comment: What specifically you wish to test? I assume you are going to write a custom KubernetesPodOperator ? You can setup `minikub` in docker and test the functionality of your custom operator against it.

Comment: Well. It can work, and there even some people who suggested that some time ago https://medium.com/bluecore-engineering/were-all-using-airflow-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it-a56f14cb0753 - but it is very limited and does not use at all Airflow's potential (and does not give you the isolation you think you have either).